# Find intervals of decrease and increase of a function $y=\frac{x^2}{2^x}$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, derivatives

Find intervals of decrease and increase of a function.

$f(x)=\frac{x^2}{2^x}$

$\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{2x \cdot 2^x-x^2\cdot4\cdot \ln2}{4^x}$

To find if it is decreasing or increasing we need it to equal $0$ but I am not sure how we can solve it.And second need to find second derivative which will be using to say $f(x)$ is positive or negative but in this situation second derivative is not good looking.

Comment: How precisely do you need the result?

Comment: Is $f=y$? If so you made an error in $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$.

Comment: I think that the derivative is wrong. The derivative of $2^x$ is $2^x \ln(2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your derivative is slightly off:
$$y=\frac{x^2}{2^x} \implies \frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=\frac{2x\cdot2^x-\ln(2)x^2\cdot2^x}{(2^x)^2}=\frac{2x-\ln(2)x^2}{2^x}$$

Comment: Won't the $2^x$ in the numerator cancel one of the $2^x$ in the denominator? So that the derivative is $\frac{3x- ln(2)x^2}{2^x}$

Comment: @user247327  $3x$ or $2x$?

Comment: 2x..........................................

Comment: @user247327 Yes, you're right. I seem to have expanded $(2^x)^2=2^{2x}=4^x$, but neglected to divide through the denominator by $2^x$. Fixed